# Getting particular keys against a given regular expression from a resource bundle

Tags: java, resources

Hi
I am using resource bundle from propertied file to fetch keys and values, like following:

ResourceBundle resouce = ResourceBundle.getBundle("", Locale.getDefault());
Enumeration bundleKeys = resouce.getKeys();

Above code fetches all the keys which is time taking.
I want to fetch particular keys with some format. e.g. keys starting with a particular keyword.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a high-level API for this (at least not in the JDK).

Why do you think you need this? What are you trying to solve? Maybe there is another way...

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Actually I am reading a file at while loading a JSP page which is taking time. So I needed it.